# Supabase order by foreign key count in select

Tags: javascript, sql, database, supabase, supabase-database

I'm trying to figure out how to sort query results using supabase to do something like this:

```js
await supabase.from("groups").select('*, items(id)').order('count(items)');
```

Basically, sort resulting groups by the number of associated items (group has many items) descending, and return those items alongside group information.

Any pointers for how to structure the `select` to do this? I'm having trouble as [docs](https://supabase.com/docs/reference/dart/order) aren't that helpful, so it's likely something I'd need raw sql for.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to create a [view](https://supabase.com/blog/2020/11/18/postgresql-views) or [database function](https://supabase.com/docs/guides/database/functions) to achieve this.

Here is an example sql to create a view.

```sql
create or replace view groups_with_items as
  select 
    -- ... any columns you would like to include in the view
    (select count(*) from public.items where public.groups.id = public.items.room_id) as count
  from public.groups
  left join public.items on public.groups.id = public.items.group_id;
```

Once you create this view, you can query this just like a regular table like this:

```js
await supabase.from("groups_with_items").select('*').order('count');
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I ended up creating a database function instead of a view.

Comment: @bryce That will work as well!